# Should I model using dependencies or associations in WSO2 GREG?

Tags: database-design, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

In WSO2 GREG you can model at least two types of relations between objects, associations and dependencies. I have seen that the Governance API differs between the two - dependencies may be somewhat more straight-forward to use for a API user. Associations can have types though.

Would you recommend the following approach?

```
if (there are more than one type of relation directed from A to B)
     use associations for this relation!
else
     use dependencies for this relation!
```

Which criteria do you use while choosing relationship type for your model?

Answer (score 0):

An association can be  defined from resource to another resource. There you can point in to resources which are stored within the registry or external URL location. When defining association you can specify the type of association such as "contains" or "uses" during association configuration. Those values help you to figure out relationship between resources.

Dependency is a specialization of associations, which states that a resource has a dependency on another resource(Ex: WSDL file depend on some Schemas).

Please refer [G-Reg Wiki Doc](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Managing+Relationships+of+a+Resource)